# SWRevealViewController with a modal Segue

Tags: ios, time, authentication, segue, swrevealviewcontroller

I am using `SWRevealViewController` for the SideMenu which has a "Login" option. Upon clicking the Login button on sideMenu `SWRevealViewController` I use a modal segue to go to `LoginViewController` . The reason I use a modal segue is because I want a "Cancel" option in my `LoginViewController` Navigation bar and also I go to `LoginVC` from other view controllers later , hence I do not want a push/SWRevealView Segue.

Problem :  After I click on Login , It takes about 30 seconds to go to Login screen .

I have print statement in "Prepareforsegue" of `Sidemenuviewcontroller` and another one in `viewdidload:` method of `LoginViewController`. The successive time between the prints is 30 seconds too. My understand is ,`SWrevealViewController` is presenting a view in between the transfers. I am not sure though.

Kindly suggest any possible workarounds